# jQuery .off("click") event does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

This has bugged me for few hours now and are still puzzled as why it does not work... when I use `table.off("click");` it works but will also unbind the click event on the 1st children which does not have the id=multi...

```js
var table = $("table#datatable")
var button = $(".generate")

function turnOffClick() {
  console.log("button clicked")
  var multiButton = $("label#multi")
  multiButton.off("click");
}

table.on("click", button, turnOffClick)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatable">
<tr>
  <td>
    <label class="generate">Generate</label>&nbsp&nbsp
    <label class="generate multi">Generate Multi</label>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're calling `off()` on an element that does not have an event handler...?

Comment: I think it has a click event handler because when I click it.. it print on the console the word "button clicked" which was added on "table.on("click", button, turnOffClick)" on labels that have the class ".generate"

Comment: The event handler is on the `table` element. If you want to disable that use `table.off('click', button, turnOffClick)`

Comment: No, the event listener is on one of his ancestor element (`table#datatable`, actually). That's why the event is fired when you click on it. But you did not explicitly add an event listener to the `label#multi element`. So you can't remove one.

Comment: After I read both of "Rory" and "Guillaume" comments... it slapped me in the face real hard... It was so simple yet I did not noticed or even thinked about it... it solved my problem thanks a lot guys :D... (huge relief and had a big laughed lol)

Comment: May not be the solution, but your label has the *class* `multi` and your code - `var multiButton = $("label#multi")` - refers to an *id* with the # symbol. To refer to a class you would need: `var multiButton = $("label.multi")`

Comment: @JamesDouglas, while I have been trying the other answers and comments and still not working... it took me a minute to notice the "multi" was on class and not on id :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use jQuery **[`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** instead if you want to detach the event after the first click.

```js
var table = $("table#datatable")

function turnOffClick() {
  console.log("button clicked");
}

table.on("click", ".generate:not(.multi)", turnOffClick);
table.one("click", "label.multi", turnOffClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label class="generate">Generate</label>&nbsp&nbsp
      <label class="generate multi">Generate Multi</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the first time I heared of one() and it was wonderful that you introduce me to it.. I could use it for my other functions too as it was also shorter

Comment: Glad I could help Brother.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting event from table but removing event from label.

```
$( "table#datatable td label" ).bind( "click", function() {
  console.log( "Sample" );
  var multiButton = $("label#multi");
  console.log(multiButton);
  $( "label#multi").off( "click" );
});
});
```

Comment: `bind`?!! really

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Do you know a reason *not* to use `bind()`?  Just curious as it was only deprecated in v3.  I personally use `on()` but that's just because I prefer the word :p

Comment: _as it was only deprecated in v3_ , it was deprecated twoooooo years ago :D

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki  Yes, in the latest version.  I'm serious - other than *"it was deprecated in the latest version"* do you have a reason not to use bind?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I'm asking a genuine question.  If you don't have a genuine answer then just say so instead of acting like you're 6.

Answer (score 0):

The event is in `table#datatable` not in `label#multi`

Try this solution:

```
var table = $("#datatable td")
var button = $(".generate")

function turnOffClick() {
   console.log("button clicked")
   var multiButton = $(this)
   multiButton.off("click");
}

table.on("click", button, turnOffClick)
```

You add the event click in all row and then the function remove the event in the clicked row